# Rails 3.0 to Rails 3.2.2 Asset handling with Jammit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

we've been using Rails 3.0 for some time. We would use jammit to compile the assets which would then be stored in /public/assets for deployment only

Problem is, we recently upgraded to Rails 3.2.2 and now Jammit is compiling the assets in the source directories which is making a mess.

Anyone else experience this. What's the right way to move from Rails 3.0 w jammit to Rails 3.2.2?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 3.1 and higher replace most of the functionality of Jammit, with a built-in process known as the Asset Pipeline.  It's is way cool, and also a pretty significant change.

There's a line in `app/config/application.rb` (for new Rails apps)

```
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true
```

Setting this to false should restore you to ancient history.  But think about migrating the code -- it's not *that* hard, and more and more gems are expecting/depending on it.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure if I'm sold yet. I'm a little lost as to what happens to the assets.yml file. Is everything now ONE HUGE file? That seems bloated. Also, Jammit supports automatic embedding of images by just using /images/embed/ it doesn't look like the asset pipeline supports this meaning the user will have to download a lot of images, slowing things down. What am I missing?

Comment: By default, yes, your CSS is a single file, JS another single file (both minified, and zipped), and images are just images (ideally sprites).  The typical bottleneck in page load is concurrent browser connections (usually 5), so fewer files is better, all other things the same.  Assuming you have your web server cache settings done properly, the user only downloads the files once.  But again, you can have Asset Pipeline create bundles for special cases just by editing the manifest files for the specific view.